# PyGTK: Make a TextView that behaves like OpenOffice's

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to make an "Office-like" TextView. That is:

- The TextView itself has a fixed width (so it kinda shows what the text would look like on a sheet of paper)
- If the window (on which the TextView is packed) is smaller than the fixed width: The TextView should be scrollable
- If the window is bigger, add margins to the left/right to keep the fixed width

This is what i came up with, and it actually behaves like it should, except that it doesn't scroll if your cursor gets out of the viewport, when you for example write a line that needs more space than the windows current width.

What would be the best way to keep the viewport "in sync"? Do I have to create a custom Viewport?

Thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# encoding: utf-8

import gtk


class SheetTextView(gtk.TextView):
    WIDTH = 700

    def __init__(self):
        gtk.TextView.__init__(self)
        self.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_WORD)
        self.set_size_request(self.WIDTH, -1)
        self.connect('size-allocate', self._on_size_allocate)

    def _on_size_allocate(self, widget, event, data=None):
        # Reset left/right margin to simulate a fixed line width
        x, y, width, height = self.get_allocation()
        if width > self.WIDTH:
            margin = (width - self.WIDTH) / 2
            self.set_left_margin(margin)
            self.set_right_margin(margin)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    window.connect('delete_event', gtk.main_quit)

    view = SheetTextView()

    scroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scroll.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
    scroll.add_with_viewport(view)

    window.add(scroll)
    window.show_all()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: add_with_viewport isn't right I think, this disables textview's built-in scrolling support.  See if adding it directly helps any: `scroll.add(view)`

Comment: That way I would loose all of the three points I mentioned. Then would be the question how to regain those. If you add the TextView with the normal `add()` there is no vertical scrolling at all, but only wrap. The TextView has no "minimal width".

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

[Dropbox link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61466577/test)

Please note this is just a test, all it does for now is change the size when necessary, 
is that what you meant?

If so, please tell me and I'll fix the bugs and improve.

EDIT: Please note this is just scratch code, messy coded...

Comment: Yeah I threw it away because I thought you weren't interested :P now searching my trash...